# Mysql community edition in enterprise

Tags: mysql, open-source, licensing

Is it illegal to use mysql server 4.x or 5.x with enterprise applications, even though the mysql was installed as part of the SuSE SLES operating system?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not at all.. MySQL is GPL. This means that if you redistribute it, or change it you must also provide the sourcecode.

**Edit** so for clarity, as long as you don't change MySQL or give it to your clients as part of a bigger package you are fine. For a hosted webapp there will be no problems for instance.